# How to use smart pointers to store an

Tags: c++, class, pointers, smart-pointers

I have two classes. One class(Person) has a vector collection composed of pointers of the other class(Student). At run time, the Person class will call a method which will store a pointer to a Student class in the vector. I have been trying to do this with smart pointers to avoid Memory leak issues that can arise but I am struggling to do so. How would I go about it?

My goal is for the Person class to have handles to objects that exist somewhere else in the code

```
Class Student
{
  public:
    string studentName
    Student(string name){
      studentName = name;
    }
}

Class Person
{
  public:
    vector <Student*> collection;
    getStudent()
   {
    cout << "input student name";
    collection.push_back(new Student(name));
   }
}
```

Comment: Start by learning about [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Note that the keyword is `class` (all lower case) not `Class`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `unique_ptr` is not what they are going to want to use.  If it was they could also just use a `vector <Student>` instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was about to post that in an answer, but there are valid reasons to have a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: I think you mean "memory leaks" when you write "Garbage collection issues". C++ has no garbage collection. Acutally C++ has no garbage to be collected ;)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili There are, but this doesn't look like a valid case for `unique_ptr`.  Reading between the lines it appears to me that the `Person` class is just supposed to have handles to objects that exist somewhere else in the code.  That would mean a `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` would be what they really want for a smart pointer.

Comment: There are several smart pointer classes, which one are you struggling with? When you are having problems with code it generally helps you get good answers if you post the code you are struggling with. That way we don't have to guess what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use smart pointers here. Place the objects directly into the vector and their lifetime is managed by the vector:

```
std::vector<Student> collection;

collection.emplace_back(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answer, you should store the Student by Value.

From a simplistic point of view, there are kinda three ways to store something in a vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>> students; 
    // an array of smart pointers

std::vector<Student*> students; // array of pointers

std::vector<Student> students; // array of objects stored by value.
```

The difference comes down to a range of things: ownership, lifetime, whether it is stored on the heap or stack.

In this case, you will likely want to store your students by value because we can safely say the 'Person' class 'owns' the list of students. When a member variable is stored by value, it sticks around only as long as the scope within which it is placed sticks around. In this case, the vector of students only sticks around so long as its parent object, an instantiantion of 'Person', sticks around.

If you are really set on storing stuff by smart pointer, however, you can do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Student> myStudent = std::make_shared<Student>(name);
students.push_back(myStudent);
```

Comment: the vectors elements are always stored on the heap. Only with `std::vector<Student*> students;` its not possible to tell where the actual students are stored

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Pedantically, it depends on the allocator, and they're not necessarily on the heap.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili true, though in the example no custom allocator is used. The `std::vector<Student*>` may point to objects on the stack